# Not able to find Msbuild file path for jenkins tool configuration

Tags: .net, jenkins, plugins, build, msbuild

our organisation is developing .net project and i have to build it using MSbuild plugin in jenkins. But i am not able to get the msbuild.exe file for Version 6, and when i installed the .net bundle v6 and added its sdk path to MSbuild file path, it throws me this error.

I am not get how can i figure out the exact msbuild path to enter and which software do i need to install on the machine where jenkins is running.

Do i have to install the Visual studio with the same version on the machine ?

Please help.

Building in workspace C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Editistrict_Build_poc
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential git

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Editistrict_Build_poc.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url http://10.125.241.100/e_district2.0.git # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from http://10.125.241.100/e_district2.0.git
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.41.0.windows.1'
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials git
> Setting http proxy: 10.125.241.80:808
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://10.125.241.100/e_district2.0.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision b8a63f61e50080f02dc2769d0af1ef4f5f0abbae (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f b8a63f61e50080f02dc2769d0af1ef4f5f0abbae # timeout=10
> Commit message: "added new files"
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk b8a63f61e50080f02dc2769d0af1ef4f5f0abbae # timeout=10
> FATAL: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.410\msbuild.exe doesn't exist
> Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.